# Calling a script from within csh with output redirection

Tags: csh, exit-status, stderr

What I would want:

```
#!/bin/csh
# call /myscriptpath/myscript.any and redirect 2>&1 and get retval and output
set my_msg = `/myscriptpath/myscript.any` 
set my_ret = `echo $?`
```

- How to capture the exit code from myscript.any?
- How to capture the message from myscript.any, if possible?

/myscriptpath/myscript.any  This works as expected called from bash command line.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way (that I know of) to handle the equivalent of `2>&1` and capture *stderr* as well as *stdout*, particularly if you want the exit status too. Piping both to `cat` will merge the output streams, though:

```
#!/usr/bin/csh
set my_tmp = ~/.msg.$$.tmp
set my_msg = `( /myscriptpath/myscript.any; echo $? >"$my_tmp" ) |& cat`
set my_ret = `cat "$my_tmp"`
rm -f "$my_tmp"

echo "ret=$my_ret, msg=$my_msg"
```

Or [alternatively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13720316/2344631), if you are running in an environment such as a Linux-based system where `/dev/stout` exists, assign `my_msg` like this:

```
set my_msg = `/myscriptpath/myscript.any >& /dev/stdout`
```

A simpler variation on `command |& cat` is to shell out to `/bin/sh` and use its redirections capability. The resulting `csh` block would then be this, with no need for `$my_tmp`,

```
#!/usr/bin/csh
set my_msg = `sh -c '/myscriptpath/myscript.any 2>&1'`
set my_ret = $status

echo "ret=$my_ret, msg=$my_msg"
```

Comment: On systems that have those, you can do `set out_and_err = \`cmd >& /dev/stdout\` `